# MySQL: Select values from table where value is in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I've been looking around for my solution for a while now with no success. I figured i'd ask the elite of web development instead..

I will try to explain this simple.

Array:

```
$image_exts = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png', 'bmp','webp');
```

What i need to do is something like this:

```
SELECT file_views 
FROM files 
WHERE file_owner='$user_id' 
AND file_ext='$image_exts'
```

the "file_ext" field in the database can contain "jpg" for one file and "mp4" for another...i only want to count views in this example for images..

Thank you for your time!

**Update 2:**

```
function count_totalviews($user_id){
    $image_exts = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png','bmp','webp');
    $image_array=implode(",", $image_exts);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT file_views FROM files WHERE file_ext IN ($image_array) AND file_owner='$user_id'");
        $count=0;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $count = $row['file_views'] + $count;
            }
        return $count;
    }
```

**PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result**

No clue what to do...

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Comment: use IN clause in query..so file_ext will check only values which are in array of $image_exts

Comment: I tried `SELECT file_views FROM files IN($image_exts) WHERE file_owner='$user_id'` didnt work

Comment: Here: `WHERE file_owner='$user_id' AND file_ext IN '$image_exts'` @Sorcher - That ought to make it kick in.

Comment: Or `WHERE file_owner='$user_id' AND file_ext IN (".$image_exts.")`

Comment: I get `PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc()` Its from `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){` ive tried _row and _array too, didnt fix it

Comment: You need to post more (actual) code then. That's a basic example that I've given you.

Comment: The answer below looks about right. I might have forgotten to put `()` around the first example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mysql's `IN`, but ensure that the parenthesized list of image extensions contains strings which are in quotes.

Your code at **Update 2** is almost there, but you have a problem at this line:

```
$image_array=implode(",", $image_exts);
```

`$image_array` ends up being `jpg,jpeg,gif,png,bmp,webp` when really you need it to be `'jpg','jpeg','gif','png','bmp','webp'` for it to be usable in your query.

Replace that line of code with:

```
$image_array = "'" . implode("','", $image_exts) . "'";
```

Keep the rest of your code, and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Use **IN**:

you can use **$image_Array=implode(",", $image_exts)** to get the list together from the array.

> SELECT file_views FROM files WHERE file_owner='$user_id' AND file_ext IN ('$image_Array')

Comment: PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: Maybe the query works but not the mysql_fetch_assoc for this example?

Comment: I think you given table name and column name Wrong, chkit

Comment: I have trippel checked it and i have manually given the $user_id but no luck, still the same error. please look at the updated post for the full php function